# Registration date

Tags: php, mysql

All I want to do is setup my database table so that when I insert a row into it then it puts the current datetime or timestamp into the registration_date field.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to do it

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aaa` (
  `date_filed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to create `registration_date` as a `timestamp` and set the default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Answer (score -1):

For "registration_date", set the default value in the database as getDate().

Comment: What should I do for the field type for it?

Comment: @zerkms: `GETDATE()` is the MS SQL pendant of `NOW()`