# Insert users join date into the database

Tags: php, mysql

How would I go about adding the current date into the database (MySQL) when a user registers? I know I would need to add a row in the database (Join_date or something), what would I set that to when creating that row? timestamp? varchar?

I want to make it so when the user submits the registration form it adds the current date to the join date row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `DATETIME` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default value. I think it's better to check MySQL syntax before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose structure is

```
field     type
++++++++++++++++++++++
id         INT
username   varchar(10)
password   varchar(10)
date       datetime
```

Then use below query

```
INSERT INTO Table values (1,'username','password',NOW())
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Column type should be `datetime`

and while inserting row, use `NOW()` in query

Comment: When the user submitting form is in a diiferent geographical location then chances are that the current date might be + or - 1 from the DB server date. Its better to get the date from the frontend.

Comment: In that case how will you check the exact time of registration. Suppose at admin end time zone is 0 and at user's end its +1:00. Id admin checks the registration time, then it will show him the future time.

Comment: So according to me Time should be stored in UTC time zone, and a separate colum for users' time zone

Answer (score 1):

Add a `datetime` column, and use [NOW()<sup>doc</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to set the column when inserting a record.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked many times.

See this question: [Registration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056454/registration-date) . Its solution can be used well; it will automatically insert date.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are using mysql, you can use field type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

usually I use `DATETIME` for created ("join date") fields and `TIMESTAMP` for lastupdated field, since it can be (easily) populated transparently by the RDBMS on update.

To get the current date  you can use mysql function `NOW()`.

for example:

```
INSERT INTO Users (`firstname`, `regdate`) VALUES ('herbie', NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make that field either MySQL internal date/time type (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html) and use CURRDATE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to fill it, or simply make it int and fill it with POSIX time with time().
Personally I find the Unix timestamp better since it's easier to operate and it doesn't depend on the type of db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this

```
INSERT INTO users (LastName, FirstName, DateColumn)
VALUES ("firstname", "lastname", NOW())
```

NOW() would insert the current date in the DateColumn field

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO users (`LastName`, `FirstName`, `DateColumn`) 
VALUES ("Fname", "LNamee", NOW())
```